# Laravel hasMany / find()->with issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Really basic problem, no doubt, but I can't for the life of me get my head around it.

I have two tables - campaigns and actions. Each action is attached to a campaign, and each campaign has many actions.

Relationships:

```
class Campaign extends Eloquent {

    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Action');
    }

class Action extends Eloquent {

    public function campaign()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Campaign');
    }
```

When querying an individual campaign, I'd like to also include the actions associated with it. My current controller method collects the actions, but shows all of the campaigns, not one:

```
class CampaignsController extends BaseController {  

    public function getCampaign($id)
        {
            $data['campaign'] = Campaign::find($id)->with('actions')->get();

            return $data;
        }
```

Campaign:find($id) finds the single campaign correctly, but how should I be bringing in the actions that belong to a single campaign, without breaking it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `get()` if you use `find()`.
  `find()` acts like the SQL clause `LIMIT 1`, as it searches your primary key and every value in that field is distinct.

```
Campaign::with('actions')->find($id);
```